# 400 error while trying to upload images to strapi

Tags: node.js, reactjs, strapi

I have a carousel in the profile, when I'm editing profile data the and uploading the existing images I'm getting 400 error from Strapi, but if I added new images everything going well but the previous images are deleted!

This is the code on the image to the backend:

```
var formData = new FormData();
imgs.forEach((img) => {
    formData.append('files', img);
});
formData.append('data', JSON.stringify(inputData));

return _post({
    name: 'uploadImages_NewOrder',
    endpoint: '/new-orders',
    isForm: true,
    sendData: formData,
});
```

and this is strapi code:

```
let profile = await getProfile(ctx);
await strapi.plugins.upload.controllers.upload.upload(ctx);
profile = await strapi.services['profile'].update({ id: profile.id }, { carousel: ctx.body });
ctx.body = pluckData(sanitizeEntity(profile, { model: strapi.models.profile }));

// return error
return 'ok';
```

I think this problem is because for the existing images it's been sent as json object not File object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.